# Flutter - flutter_inappwebview - GL error: Out of memory

Tags: flutter

I use the `flutter_inappwebview` plugin to run a WebView (`PostUrl`). but I found an error when displaying my web. Here's an example of my coding:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert' show utf8;
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';
import 'package:smartmosque/Api/ApiServer.dart';
import 'package:smartmosque/Utils/Global.dart';

class PaymentLinkAjaPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String token;

  PaymentLinkAjaPage({this.token});

  @override
  _PaymentLinkAjaPageState createState() => _PaymentLinkAjaPageState();
}

class _PaymentLinkAjaPageState extends State<PaymentLinkAjaPage> {
  InAppWebViewController webView;
  String url = "";
  double progress = 0;

  void actionBack() {
    if (url.length > 100) {
      Navigator.pop(context);
      Navigator.pop(context);
      Navigator.pop(context);
    } else {
      Navigator.pop(context);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () {
        actionBack();
        return Future.value(true);
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Global.primaryRed,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Infak Link Aja!"),
          elevation: 0,
          leading: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
              onPressed: () {
                actionBack();
              }),
        ),
        body: Container(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
                  child: progress < 1.0
                      ? LinearProgressIndicator(value: progress)
                      : Container()),
              Expanded(
                  child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                    topRight: Radius.circular(20)),
                child: InAppWebView(
                  initialHeaders: {},
                  initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
                      crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
                          debuggingEnabled: true,
                          useShouldOverrideUrlLoading: false)),
                  onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {
                    webView = controller;
                    var encodetext = utf8.encode("message=${widget.token}");
                    Uint8List postdata = Uint8List.fromList(encodetext);
                    webView.postUrl(url: urlWebLinkAja, postData: postdata);
                  },
                  androidOnPermissionRequest:
                      (InAppWebViewController controller, String origin,
                          List<String> resources) async {
                    return PermissionRequestResponse(
                        resources: resources,
                        action: PermissionRequestResponseAction.GRANT);
                  },
                  onReceivedServerTrustAuthRequest:
                      (controller, challenge) async {
                    return ServerTrustAuthResponse(
                        action: ServerTrustAuthResponseAction.PROCEED);
                  },
                  onLoadStart:
                      (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) async {
                    setState(() {
                      this.url = url;
                      // print("urlstart: $url");
                    });
                  },
                  onLoadStop: (controller, url) async {
                    setState(() {
                      this.url = url;
                    });
                  },
                  onProgressChanged:
                      (InAppWebViewController controller, int progress) {
                    setState(() {
                      this.progress = progress / 100;
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ))
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and here's the error log:

```
E/OpenGLRenderer( 5918): GL error:  Out of memory!
F/OpenGLRenderer( 5918): glFinish error! GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY (0x505)
W/google-breakpad( 5918): ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###
W/google-breakpad( 5918): Chrome build fingerprint:
W/google-breakpad( 5918): 70.0.3538.110
W/google-breakpad( 5918): 353811052
W/google-breakpad( 5918): ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###
F/libc    ( 5918): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 6041 (RenderThread), pid 5918 (gma.example)
Softversion: PD1731F_EX_A_1.18.3
Time: 2020-09-28 15:17:37
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'vivo/1724/1724:8.1.0/OPM1.171019.011/compil08311518:user/release-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'arm64'
pid: 5918, tid: 6041, name: RenderThread  >>> com.example.test <<<
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
Abort message: 'glFinish error! GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY (0x505)'
    x0   0000000000000000  x1   0000000000001799  x2   0000000000000006  x3   0000000000000008
    x4   0000007b2cd44588  x5   0000007b2cd44588  x6   0000007b2cd44588  x7   0000007b2cd44588
    x8   0000000000000083  x9   0000000010000000  x10  0000007b2cd43cb0  x11  8f38f30250d84677
    x12  8f38f30250d84677  x13  0000000000000000  x14  ffffffffffffffdf  x15  8f38f30250d84677
    x16  0000005f418bffa8  x17  0000007bd2ec4134  x18  8f38f30250d84677  x19  000000000000171e
    x20  0000000000001799  x21  0000000000000083  x22  0000007bd29a9a70  x23  0000000000000502
    x24  0000007bd29a9b3e  x25  0000000000000505  x26  0000007bd29a9b24  x27  0000007bd29a9b3e
    x28  0000000000000505  x29  0000007b2cd43cf0  x30  0000007bd2e6a630
    sp   0000007b2cd43cb0  pc   0000007bd2e6a658  pstate 0000000060000000
backtrace:
    #00 pc 000000000001e658  /system/lib64/libc.so (abort+120)
    #01 pc 00000000000083e4  /system/lib64/liblog.so (__android_log_assert+296)
    #02 pc 00000000000468fc  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::debug::GlesErrorCheckWrapper::assertNoErrors(char const*)+384)
    #03 pc 0000000000089b00  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::Caches::flush(android::uirenderer::Caches::FlushMode)+164)
    #04 pc 00000000000752fc  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::Bridge_destroyHardwareResources(android::uirenderer::renderthread::destroyHardwareResourcesArgs*)+12)
    #05 pc 0000000000076934  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::MethodInvokeRenderTask::run()+24)
    #06 pc 0000000000076cc8  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::SignalingRenderTask::run()+28)
    #07 pc 0000000000077c18  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::RenderThread::threadLoop()+336)
    #08 pc 0000000000011590  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+276)
    #09 pc 00000000000aa03c  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+136)
    #10 pc 0000000000077968  /system/lib64/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+36)
    #11 pc 000000000001fa30  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+68)
Lost connection to device.
```

Running `flutter doctor`:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.20.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1082], locale en-US)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
[√] Android Studio (version 3.6)
[√] VS Code (version 1.49.2)
[√] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

Comment: am alos getting the same error but when using agora video conference...how did you solve it?